# Raspberry Pi HDMI no signal

Tags: hdmi, display

I've just got my raspberry pi.

When I first tried, everything went on well, I got the image on me TV and I tried to set wireless connections.

But when I was trying, the screen suddenly displayed "no signal", I tried to reboot(just cut the power off)my pi but it didn't work. I tried several other times and checked the connections, but they seemed all good.

Later I searched on the Internet for the solution. I tried some but nothing worked.

Now as I give the pi the power supply. The PWR light goes steady red and the OK light flashes green for a while and then goes out. No other signals at all.

I really need some advice, how can I get image on my TV again? Do I need to change other settings or am I simply better to buy another pi or another HDMI cable? Any idea or solution is really welcomed and appreciated!

PS: I can see the dim ACT light flashing

Comment: please, try to reverse the HDMI cable, connect the end that went into the TV to RasPI and vice versa, might solve this problem.

Comment: If you are getting a short green but then not getting a long green, that usually indicates that it is not booting correctly.  Usually that is a result of data corruption on the card but could also be a hardware problem.  Have you tried pulling ut the card and reseating it?  Do you have another SD card loaded with an image (even NOOBS) that you can try to make sure it isn't the socket?

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you to re-flash your SD Card(i.e your OS).There are chances that the one/more of your vital OS files got corrupted,resulting into your Pi unable to detect any valid OS(statup problem).

The no-signal is a consequence of the above problem.....Hope you get to use your Pi once,you re-flash it again.

N.B: In-case you purchased a pre-loaded SD Card....here are the steps to do it again yourself.

Assuming you have a linux box handy.............

1. Download your favorite Raspberry Pi OS image from [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads).
2. Insert the SD card into a linux box.
3. Open terminal, and execute $df -l
4. You get a list of all storage devices connected to the computer,
   try to deduce your SD card from its size/name.

   Eg: /dev/mmcblk0
5. To re-flash the SD card,we need to unmount it,this way:

   $umount /dev/mmcblk0
6. Assuming your pwd[present working directory] has the OS image,execute the following command.

   $dcfldd bs=4M if=.img of=/dev/mmcblk0

   Note: This process may take several minutes,any interruption may result in SD   becoming corrupted.

7.Now, you have a re-flashed SD card,slide into your raspberry, and hope this gives you smile in your face,

Comment: This comment is from July 2017 - Agree with everything said here except recommend use Win32DiskImager to transfer the image to the SD card.

Answer (score 2):

My initial start-up 'problem' with my new Pi was No Screen Image - this simply turned out to be the HDMI cable connector not fully fitting into the Pi socket because I first fitted the Pi into an RS box bought to protect the Pi.
Without the box everything worked: once I'd doctored the male connection (cut back the plastic encapsulation a tad) it all worked fine when back in the box. 
As a general rule - To succeed in life you need good connections.

Comment: I like your general rule.  Upvote just for that.

Answer (score 2):

Strangely enough I had this same problem last Wednesday. I at first thought it was the HDMI, as realistically no signal means not, "No connection" (check signal wire - bad cable) but means no data/no signal (bad send/no send).

Thinking I destroyed my pi while transporting it, I tried reposting the pi, checking the disk image, checked solderer connections, power usb in, even swapped the HDMI cable. I didn't have the luxury of testing with a volt meter or changing my display.

In the end, I found by wiggling the connection for the power input caused the screen to spark a rainbow colour and made the HDMI connection connect.

My untested theory is that: perhaps that when underpowered, the HDMI cannot fully enable, or otherwise provide enough power to operate a successful connection. Leading to a "No Data/No signal"

I tested this on another pi, and got the same results.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using NOOBS to set up you PI, you might want to check the INSTRUCTIONS-README, that comes with NOOBS. This did not help me to fix it, but might be worth a try anyway:

If your display remains blank, you should select the correct output mode for your display by pressing one of the following number keys on your keyboard:

1. HDMI mode - this is the default display mode.
2. HDMI safe mode - select this mode if you are using the HDMI connector and cannot see anything on screen when the Pi has booted.
3. Composite PAL mode - select either this mode or composite NTSC mode if you are using the composite RCA video connector.
4. Composite NTSC mode